# How to capture a array of select statements in php

Tags: php, html

The below code fetch the result as per the mysql query and based on the count 
equal number of select options r created below

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $cid = $row['customerid'];
                ?>
                <tr class="style4" >
                    <td><?php echo $liveCustomerCount; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $cid; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['customername']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['area']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['mobileno']; ?></td>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>" name="cid[]"/>
               <td><input type="text" placeholder="KG" name="quanty[]" size="12" id="tat<?php echo $xx; ?>" onKeyUp="totaling();" value="<?php echo @$row['quantity'];?>"/></td>
               <td><input type="text" placeholder="KG" name="delivery[]" size="12" value="<?php echo 1;?>"/></td>
               <td><select name="calctype[<?php echo $xx; ?>]"> 
               <option> Select </option>
               <?php $calc = mysqli_query($con,"select distinct calctype from liveinvoices");
               while($type = mysqli_fetch_assoc($calc)){ ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $type['calctype']; ?>" > <?php echo $type['calctype']; ?> </option> <?php } ?>
               </select>


               </td>
                </tr>
    <?php $xx++;
    $liveCustomerCount++;
} ?>
```

Now i want to submit all the records at once

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$today = date('Y-m-d');
for ($axs = 0; $axs < count($_REQUEST['cid']); $axs++) {
            $option=$_REQUEST['calctype'][$axs];
```

value captured is SELECT instead of the value selected in the UI

Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name="calctype[<?php echo $xx; ?>]"
```

Should be on the

```
<select>
```

element.

Comment: Is the html rendering properly with <select name="caltype[0]"> ?